# Google Maps JS APi v3 fusion table layer is not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

I set up a google map with country overlay through fusion table layer functionality.

Works perfectly here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYLPNO

```js
function loadMap() {
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.type = 'text/javascript';
   //script.src = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=' + settings.api_key + '&' + 'callback=initMap';
     script.src = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp' + '&' + 'callback=initMap';
   document.body.appendChild(script);
  }

initMap = function() {
   var google = window.google || {};

    var c_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(30,0),
     zoom: 2,
     disableDefaultUI: true,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var world_geometry = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
     query: {
      select: 'geometry',
      from: '1N2LBk4JHwWpOY4d9fobIn27lfnZ5MDy-NoqqRpk',
      where: "Name IN ('Russia','France')"
     },
     styles: [{
      where: "Name = 'France'",
      markerOptions: {
      iconName: 'red_circle'
     },
      polygonOptions: {
       fillColor: '#EB6841',
       fillOpacity: 0.3
      }
     }, {
      where: "Name = 'Russia'",
      polygonOptions: {
       fillColor: '#00A0B0',
       fillOpacity: 0.5
      }
     }],
     map: c_map,
     suppressInfoWindows: true
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(world_geometry, 'click', function(e) {
     document.location.href = document.location.protocol + '//' + document.location.host + '/countries/' + e.row.Name.value.toLowerCase();
    });
   };
loadMap();
```

```css
#map-canvas, html, body {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  z-index: 2;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: 20px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
height: 300px;
line-height: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0 #333
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

But the same code embeded into my site is working in Firefox (windows, mac, android), Safari (iOS, Mac), IE11 (Windows) but does NOT work on Chrome (Mac, Windows, Android).

There are no javascript errors, map just displays without overlay. I even tried to delete ALL js on my page except for this one. I've also replicated styles exactly as they are on my site (as you can see in codepen).

Unfortunately I cannot give you a link to my site, it is hosted on my laptop for now.

Any ideas how to debug this?

Comment: Both, the codepen & the code snippet work for me in chrome.

Comment: @Dr.Molle yeah, for me too. But somehow the same code does not work when placed somewhere in my page. I can't understand how to debug this...

Comment: Impossible to help you without seeing the live example(which didn't work)

Comment: @Dr.Molle I guess so:( I plan to go live with this today, I'll update question with the link.

Comment: @Dr.Molle oddly enough it is now working on live site (though I now face a problem of API key not working). Thanks for participation;)

Comment: @Dr.Molle raising the dead... I've recently played with API keys, now maps are working properly but FT layer not... You can see it here http://perlovs.com/countries/israel/ by pressing the button (it is in Russian, so here is screenshot with button higlighted http://imgur.com/XaJhFyE)

Comment: I can see the layer(polygons for different countries, e.g. israel,cyprus,spain)

Comment: @Dr.Molle in Chrome? It works for me in Firefox, IE, etc...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that the question was about chrome. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a CSS-issue, forced by this rule(in style.cab.css):

```
img{max-width:100%;}
```

add this rule:

```
 #map-canvas img{max-width:none;}
```

Comment: I was zooming and panning a little bit, then the layer did appear, but distorted.  So I thought it must be related to CSS(the `max-width` is often the source of map-related issues, so I only needed to look if it has been set somewhere)