# Google Map API - Fusion Table Layer not showing in Chrome

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, google-fusion-tables

I have created a Google map using the API and data from a Fusion Table.  It works fine in Firefox, but the layer styling (polygons) does not display in Chrome. It appears to be there as it's clickable...etc. and if I zoom and pan it will eventually show up.

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
map: map,
heatmap: { enabled: false },
suppressInfoWindows: true,
query: {
 select: "col2\x3e\x3e0",
 from: FusionTableID,
 where: ""
  },
  options: {
    styleId: 2,
    templateId: 3
  }

});

layer.setMap(map);
```

Comment: impossible to answer based on the given code, maybe a [CSS-issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27899989/google-maps-js-api-v3-fusion-table-layer-is-not-working-in-chrome/28679166#28679166)

Answer (score 2):

Found this thread and it seems to have resolved the issue!
[Google Maps JS APi v3 fusion table layer is not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27899989/google-maps-js-api-v3-fusion-table-layer-is-not-working-in-chrome)

need to add this style:

```
 #map-canvas img{max-width:none;}
```

Comment: Exact issue here and it drove me batty - network showed the fusion table data returned from the webservice, and no exceptions at all in the console. I had a designer-friendly development environment setup (no webserver, compiled JSX and less in-browser) that only worked on Firefox, so assumed that it wasn't working because I broke something when I transitioned to the new env. Turns out it this happens when your theme sets an img with "max-width: 100%", because the containing element for map img's is 0x0, and the images are technically overflow.